# Angular CLI - Lazy Loading - No chunks

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've implemented lazy loading in a couple of projects. One of our biggest projects was still loading everything eagerly. So I've changed that to use lazy loading.
The app is working, but Angular CLI still only generates one big main.js file, no chunks.
I know that this happens when there is an import statement somewhere, but I'm very sure there is none. 
E.g. I've got a lazy-loading module in `/create-booking`. The only reference to `/create-booking` is the loadChildren element.

All of my modules are in the "modules" folder and the only references are in loadChildren.

The weird thing though is that when I navigate to a lazy loaded module, it takes 1-2 seconds for the site to respond. But nothing is displayed in the network tab :(

My project is too big to share. What could I do to investigate this further?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If not, can you post the output of your ng build here?

Comment: Nah in the end I've made all bundles non-lazy loading, as I had more issues with lazy loading.

Comment: Hmm that's a shame as I think it is the key to a quick loading SPA - but I also am battling to get it to chunk properly...

Comment: @Rodney changing to AOT had a very big impact. From ~3 seconds the site is now loading in < 1 second! And the total bundle size is about 5mb (gzipped 500kb) so pretty good I think :)

Comment: I actually thought AOT was a future feature and not implemented in CLI - I  will give it a try, thanks

Comment: So I finally got AOT working, and yes, the difference is massive - very impressive. The annoying thing with the lazy-loaded routes is that they work fine, they just don't chunk correctly. I can make a few tweaks to my project and get it to chunk but I can't figure out exactly what the problem is that is causing chunking of the lazt loaded routes to cease working... https://github.com/rodneyjoyce/lazy-routes